# python gnupg decrypt error

Tags: python, urllib2, gnupg

I'm new to Python and I want to decrypt a downloadable PGP encrypted file in Python using gnupg module (http://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/) (I thought that simple API calls should be easy but I have wasted so much time on this that I thought of getting some help).

So I'm able to download a file from the url in Python, and I tried decryping it with Gpg4win software, and it works well. I get different errors when I try to decrypt it in Python using gnupg module.

Ideally I would like to download the file from the url, and decrypt it, and then store it in a file (Rather than downloading the file, saving it, decryting the file, saving a new decypted file)

This is my prototype code:

```
#test

import urllib2
import gnupg

z='https://abcd_url'
u = urllib2.urlopen(z)
localFile = open('file_haha_test2', 'w+b')
localFile.write(u.read())

gpg = gnupg.GPG()
#gpg.encoding = 'utf-8'

##gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GNU\\Desktop\\GnuPG',
##                                gpgbinary='C:\\Program Files          (x86)\\GNU\\Desktop\\GnuPG\\gpg.exe',
##                                keyring='C:\\user\\Desktop\\Encryption keys\\secret-key-73F.asc')


status = str(gpg.decrypt(u.read(), passphrase='hp',  output='HAHAHAH.txt'))     

#status = str(gpg.decrypt_file(localFile, passphrase='hp',output='HAHAHAH.txt'))

#status = gpg.decrypt_file(localFile)

print status

#localFile.close()
```

I got different errors for different syntax(You can see them commented above). Currently I'm getting not getting any output on the screen. I think it should print the contents.

I really want to get this working as quickly as possible and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Save `u.read()` in a variable. I think the second `u.read() == ''`

Comment: Okay, I tried: 

     link = u.read()
    
..and put link in place of u.read() in the next line. Still no change

Comment: and do you do `localFile.write(link)`?

Comment: This is the next line. I have commented localFile. Just trying to print it on screen first:

status = str(gpg.decrypt(link, passphrase='harry potter', output='HAHAHAH.txt'))

Comment: Hey, this worked. I can open the decrypted file HAHAHAH.txt. It doesn't print it on the screen though, but that doesn't matter.
*Furiously works more on it*. I'll re-post if I get stuck again(sorry to trouble you!). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the library [on PyPI as ‘gnupg’](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gnupg).

Have you tried the library [on PyPI as ‘python-gnupg’](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-gnupg)?

The two libraries have quite similar APIs, and both have activity in recent years. I don't know which is better in general.